# how to fix 'String cannot be resolved to a type'

Tags: java

when i compile the code in eclipse, throwing error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    String cannot be resolved to a type
    String cannot be resolved to a type
    System cannot be resolved
    String cannot be resolved to a type
    System cannot be resolved   "
```

but i have written "String" from capital "S"

Below is the code :

```
 public class student {
        int id;
        String name;
    }

class TestStudent1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        student s = new student();
        s.name = "ram";
        s.id = 101;
        System.out.println(s.name);
        System.out.println(s.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code causing this error to be thrown

Comment: you have probably missed out a semicolon or bracket

Comment: Go back and put " On the side of the string that it's seams to be missing from

Comment: E.g. String a = "test_string";

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved your files and make TestStudent1 class public and change the file name as TestStudent1.java as below,

```
class student {
    int id;
    String name;
}

public class TestStudent1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    student s = new student();
    s.name = "ram";
    s.id = 101;
    System.out.println(s.name);
    System.out.println(s.id);
}
}
```

here is the output:

ram
101

Comment: Add it to your question so it looks like code.  You can do this by clicking edit post.  The press space bar 4 times then add the code

Comment: my code is                 this is code which i have writtenpackage Java;

public class student
{

  int id;
  String name; 

 }

 class TestStudent1
 
 {
 
 public static void main (String []args)
 {
  
  student s= new student();
  s.name="ram";
  s.id=101;
  
  System.out.println(s.name);
  System.out.println(s.id);
    
  
 }
 }